# MySql driver not visible in Vendor list STS

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to set up Hibernate with my Spring app.
In Step 5, mysql doesnt show up in vendor combobox. I tried setting classpath also but no use. Please help.
http://www.javahelps.com/2015/08/add-mysql-jdbc-driver-to-eclipse.html

Comment: You don't need to configure your MySQL database in STS in order to use it with your Spring Boot app.

Comment: In case you want to access the database from within the IDE using the Eclipse Datatools, you need to install those into STS (they are not installed by default) and make sure you have the MySQL parts of that installed, too.

Comment: Thank you, it started appearing once I installed Data tools.